# Salesforce Eclipse IDE not showing custom fields on object

Tags: ide, salesforce, force.com

I recently upgraded to Windows 8.1, and am now having issues with the Force.com IDE.
When I select Force.com->Add/remove metadata components, I'm not able to see any custom field child component in the Objects-Custom component. Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should refresh metadata from server? For this just click "Refresh from Server" button in top right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2015, I had the same problem and the issue was the current incompatibility of Java 8, Eclipse Kepler (or Juno) and the current Force.com IDE. I had to (1) uninstall Java 8 completely; (2) re-install Eclipse Kepler--basically unzip the *.gz to a new folder; (3) find an archive download for Java 7 and install it; and (4) re-install the Force.com IDE.  This was the only series of steps that completely fixed the problem.  All components of custom objects are now available to me in the components tree.  My computer's OS is Windows 7 64-bit.